# "selector is not an known element" angular

Tags: angular

I know this has been asked several times but after going through all the answers it still does not solve my problem. I'm trying to use the the selector of "GetToursComponent" which is in the "AppModule" into the "WelcomeComponent" which is in "General Module". The error I am getting is in the picture that is attached.

code:

1) app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    GetToursComponent,
    PostToursComponent,
    ToursDetailsComponent,
    EditTourComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ServicesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    GeneralModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [GetToursComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2) general.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    generalRoutingModule
  ], 
  exports:[HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
})
export class GeneralModule { }
```

3) welcome.component.ts

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
    <app-get-tours></app-get-tours>
</div>


<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()">
    <h2>welcome to natours </h2>

    <h1>login</h1>
    <a routerLink="/auth/login">login</a>
    <br>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <a routerLink="/auth/register">register</a>
</div>
```

4) app.routing.ts

```
let AuthRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', loadChildren: './general/general.module#GeneralModule'},
    { path: 'auth/login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'auth/register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'getTours', component: GetToursComponent },
    { path: 'createTour', component: PostToursComponent },
    { path: 'toursDetails/:id', component: ToursDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'editTour/:id', component: EditTourComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(AuthRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

5) general.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: WelcomeComponent }
]

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class generalRoutingModule {}
```

Error :

[image: Error]

[gettours component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGpUH.png)

Comment: Can you post the component decorator for `GetToursComponent`

Comment: have you added that component into main modules   declarations: [...] array? seems you missed there

Comment: which component? welcome component? no I havent? thats the reason I made the module; to not include all the components into the main one

Comment: @KurtHamilton done

Answer (score 2):

Your general module doesn't know about `GetToursComponent`, and yet `WelcomeComponent` - which is declared in general module - is trying to use it.

You have 2 options:

1. Create a shared module that declares and exports `GetToursComponent`, and import that into both modules
2. Declare `GetToursComponent` in general module and export it, like below.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    GetToursComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    generalRoutingModule
  ], 
  exports:[HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, GetToursComponent]
})
export class GeneralModule { }
```

For both options you have to remove the declaration of `GetToursComponent` from app module - it will be imported from whichever module you export it from.

Comment: I would recommend the first approach as the OP's `GeneralModule` clearly consists of generic components. Create a new module and name it as you wish (SharedModule / TourModule). Declare and export the Tour components here. Now import this new module in both GeneralModule and AppModule. This should resolve the errors.

Comment: Me too. But then that's just our opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your `GetToursComponent` from `AppModule` and add it to `GeneralModule` into exports and declarations array.